# Python Django URL Match Issues with Anchor Tag

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I have a question regarding why Django isn't matching my the url in an anchor tag in my template. I'm finding that in this one instance, if I put a button inside an anchor tag, Django won't match it because it looks for a trailing slash. If I put the button inside a form, it matches fine.

```
<a href="/reset"><button>Reset my account</button></a>
```

The above code returns a 404 error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in main.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^ ^$
^ ^process$
^ ^checkout$
^ ^reset$
The current URL, reset/, didn't match any of these.
```

If I put the button inside form tags, it works fine:

```
<form action="/reset">
<input type="submit" value="Reset my account">
</form>
```

Alternately, if I add a trailing slash to the path in my_app/urls.py, the anchor tag will work:

```
url(r'^reset/$', views.reset)
```

Why is Django trying to match a trailing slash in this instance? I have used this approach before without issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Check your settings.py middleware to have 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', Also you can set APPEND_SLASH  to True in settings.py

Comment: I do have 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware' in settings.py middleware. I've also tried adding 'APPEND_SLASH = True' in settings.py, but it didn't seem to have any effect. Does it matter where it is placed?

Comment: What do you mean by ""_Alternately, if I add a trailing slash to the path in my_app/urls.py, the anchor tag will work_:

`url(r'^reset/$', views.reset)`  .""....  so you were using your urls as `url(r'^reset$', views.reset)`  without **slash** before ?

Comment: I mean it should be like this only : `url(r'^reset/$', views.reset) ` i.e with slash

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I was using

'code'url(r'^reset$', views.reset)

I was told this was normal practice, but thank you for telling me this is not so. I will add the trailing slash in my app urls.py from now on.

Comment: Apologies for not formatting the code in my comments, I didn't figure out how to do it before the timer ran out.

I am curious, if a trailing slash should always be added, and the default Django setting is APPEND_SLASH = True, what is APPEND_SLASH doing? It doesn't appear to append a trailing slash if one is not added in urls.py.